# Building an Electron app fails using Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, electron, electron-builder

I'm trying to build an Electron app using Azure DevOps. It fails with the following error:

```
Package Electron App for Platform win...
  • electron-builder  version=21.2.0 os=4.15.0-1052-azure
  • artifacts will be published if draft release exists  reason=CI detected
  • loaded configuration  file=/home/vsts/work/1/s/FotoManager/obj/desktop/win/bin/electron-builder.json
  • packaging       platform=win32 arch=x64 electron=5.0.8 appOutDir=/home/vsts/work/1/s/FotoManager/bin/Desktop/win-unpacked
  • downloading     url=https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v5.0.8/electron-v5.0.8-win32-x64.zip size=59 MB parts=4
  • downloaded      url=https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v5.0.8/electron-v5.0.8-win32-x64.zip duration=1.859s
  • downloading     url=https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder-binaries/releases/download/winCodeSign-2.5.0/winCodeSign-2.5.0.7z size=5.6 MB parts=1
  • downloaded      url=https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder-binaries/releases/download/winCodeSign-2.5.0/winCodeSign-2.5.0.7z duration=1.593s
  ⨯ wine is required, please see https://electron.build/multi-platform-build#linux  
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-builder/node_modules/app-builder-bin/linux/x64/app-builder exited with code ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_CANNOT_EXECUTE  stackTrace=
    Error: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-builder/node_modules/app-builder-bin/linux/x64/app-builder exited with code ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_CANNOT_EXECUTE
        at ChildProcess.childProcess.once.code (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-builder/node_modules/builder-util/src/util.ts:239:14)
        at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
        at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
        at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
    From previous event:
        at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
        at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
        at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
    From previous event:
        at WinPackager.signApp (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-builder/node_modules/app-builder-lib/src/winPackager.ts:357:27)
        at WinPackager.doPack (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-builder/node_modules/app-builder-lib/src/platformPackager.ts:243:16)
... done
```

A local build on Win10 works without any problem.

This is my pipeline YAML: https://github.com/mu88/BlazorFotoManager/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml

As you can see, I'm installing Wine, as recommended [here](https://www.electron.build/multi-platform-build#to-build-app-for-windows-on-linux).

Any ideas how to solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I solved it by simply using a Windows VM Image.

Comment: what was the image called? I have similar issues, but all the images i tried did not help so far. Or did you build your own?

Comment: @modmoto I think OP meant that he just used a hosted windows image to perform the build. I also experienced issues when trying to use the electronuser builder image and just resolved to use `vmImage: 'windows-latest'` in my azure pipelines YAML.

Comment: I switched over to GitHub Actions, which looks like [this](https://github.com/mu88/BlazorFotoManager/blob/main/.github/workflows/CI.yml) - it might be similar for Azure DevOps

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur on all CI Pipelines. I faced it on GitLab CI, since it builds it on a Linux machine.

The solution in GitLab CI was to use the image `electronuserland/builder:wine` as recommended in [the official docs](https://www.electron.build/multi-platform-build#to-build-app-for-windows-on-linux)

[Example .gitlab-ci.yml file](https://gitlab.com/cataxcab/the-wall/-/commit/e550969db641398f829525edb96ee91691b5b7a6)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the wine problem by creating a task before generating the exe to run a shellscript where I perform all the steps to install wine on vm ubuntu